# How to wrap XML-content in a new node (Nokogiri, Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri I want to insert a node `<inserted_node>` into the following XML-snipplet

```
<foo>
   <bar>some text</bar>
</foo>
```

like that

```
<foo>
   <inserted_node>
      <bar>some text</bar>
   </inserted_node>
</foo>.
```

How can this be achieved with Nokogiri?

Comment: Is `<foo>` the root node or is it just something you cut out of the real XML?

Comment: it's somewhere in the DOM

Comment: Then see the last part of my answer, which covers grafting in at an arbitrary node.

Answer (score 4):

Nokogiri has a method conveniently called `wrap`.

```
doc.search("bar").wrap("<inserted_node>")
doc.to_html

 => <foo>
        <inserted_node><bar>some text</bar></inserted_node>
    </foo>
```

To answer the followup question:

```
str = "<foo><bar1></bar1><bar2></bar2></foo>"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(str)
doc.search("bar1,bar2").map(&:parent).uniq.each do |node|
  # Create a new element to attach the children to
  inserted = doc.create_element("inserted")

  # Move the children into the new element
  inserted.children = node.children

  # Add the new element as a child of the parent node
  node << inserted
end

=> "<foo><inserted><bar1></bar1><bar2></bar2></inserted></foo>"
```

Comment: And what if `<foo>` had the child-nodes `<bar1>` and `<bar2>`and I wanted to wrap the two nodes with `<inserted_node>`?

Comment: That's a little more complex, but you'd basically `search` to find all nodes you want to wrap, get a unique list of their parents, then for each parent, grab all its children, insert a new node under that parent, and move all the children under the parent.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo>
   <bar>some text</bar>
</foo>
EOT

children = doc.root.children
doc.root.children = '<inserted_node>'
doc.at('inserted_node').children = children
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <foo>
# >>   <inserted_node>
# >>    <bar>some text</bar>
# >> </inserted_node>
# >> </foo>
```

If there's more content it still works the same:

```
<foo>
   <bar>some text</bar>
   <baz>some more text</baz>
</foo>
```

Running it again:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo>
   <bar>some text</bar>
   <baz>some more text</baz>
</foo>
EOT

children = doc.root.children
doc.root.children = '<inserted_node>'
doc.at('inserted_node').children = children
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <foo>
# >>   <inserted_node>
# >>    <bar>some text</bar>
# >>    <baz>some more text</baz>
# >> </inserted_node>
# >> </foo>
```

If you want to do this farther inside a DOM:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo>
   <sub_foo>
     <bar>some text</bar>
     <baz>some more text</baz>
   </sub_foo>
</foo>
EOT

NODE_TO_INSERT = 'inserted_node'

graft_node = doc.at('sub_foo')
children = graft_node.children
graft_node.children = "<#{ NODE_TO_INSERT }>"
doc.at(NODE_TO_INSERT).children = children
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <foo>
# >>    <sub_foo><inserted_node>
# >>      <bar>some text</bar>
# >>      <baz>some more text</baz>
# >>    </inserted_node></sub_foo>
# >> </foo>
```

The idea is, you point to where you're going to modify the document by getting that node. I used `doc.at('sub_foo')` because there was only one. You could `search` if you had a number of places to manipulate, and then iterate over the resulting NodeSet. Once you know the node you're going to work on, grab its children and remember them in a variable, change the child under the grafting point, then reinsert the old children under that node.

Once you grok this, you can mangle XML and HTML easily.